# Get all videos from channel - Youtube API v3 c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, youtube-api

Is it possible to get all videos from a channel (not mine)?
If it is possible, can I use a simple API key or should I use OAuth 2.0 credentials?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have done in this way and it worked for me
I have used Youtube API v3 from Nuget Packet manager

```
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;

public ActionResult GetVideo(YouTubeData objYouTubeData)
{
    try
    {
        var yt = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = "Your API Key" });
        var channelsListRequest = yt.Channels.List("contentDetails");
        channelsListRequest.ForUsername = "kkrofficial";
        var channelsListResponse = channelsListRequest.Execute();
        foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
        {
            // of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
            var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;
            var nextPageToken = "";
            while (nextPageToken != null)
            {
                var playlistItemsListRequest = yt.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
                // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                var playlistItemsListResponse = playlistItemsListRequest.Execute();
                foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                {
                    // Print information about each video.
                    //Console.WriteLine("Video Title= {0}, Video ID ={1}", playlistItem.Snippet.Title, playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                    var qry = (from s in ObjEdbContext.ObjTubeDatas where s.Title == playlistItem.Snippet.Title select s).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (qry == null)
                    {
                        objYouTubeData.VideoId = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId;
                        objYouTubeData.Title = playlistItem.Snippet.Title;
                        objYouTubeData.Descriptions = playlistItem.Snippet.Description;
                        objYouTubeData.ImageUrl = playlistItem.Snippet.Thumbnails.High.Url;
                        objYouTubeData.IsValid = true;
                        ObjEdbContext.ObjTubeDatas.Add(objYouTubeData);
                        ObjEdbContext.SaveChanges();
                        ModelState.Clear();

                    }
                }
                nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Some exception occured" + e;
        return RedirectToAction("GetYouTube");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("GetYouTube");
}
```

Provide your channel name in this line

```
channelsListRequest.ForUsername = "kkrofficial"; //kkrofficial is kkr channel name.
```

Follow this link
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads

Comment: What about ClientServiceRequest.cs? Should I have this ?

Comment: I've created API but in my application I got error message: Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration. [403]

Comment: ClientServiceRequest.cs not required...Just Youtube API v3 from Nuget Packet manager install that set

Answer (score 5):

You can use your API key and just query all channels video ( even if not yours :) )

```
        public Task<List<SearchResult>> GetVideosFromChannelAsync(string ytChannelId)
    {

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            List<SearchResult> res = new List<SearchResult>();

            string nextpagetoken = " ";

            while (nextpagetoken != null)
            {
                var searchListRequest = _youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
                searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                searchListRequest.ChannelId = ytChannelId;
                searchListRequest.PageToken = nextpagetoken;
                searchListRequest.Type      = "video";

                // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
                var searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();

                // Process  the video responses 
                res.AddRange(searchListResponse.Items);

                nextpagetoken = searchListResponse.NextPageToken;

            }

            return res;

        });
    }
```

This method should get you on track

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example on how to output video names for a channel using a console app.

You will need an API key. To get an API key,

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/

Use your gmail account to log in.

Click on Enable APIs and services (or go to APIs and services if you already enabled it).

In the API Library page, search for youtube.

Select Youtube Data API v3.

Click on Enable to enable API.

Click on Credentials on the left side menu (or click on Manage, then Credentials if it's already enabled).

Click on Create Credentials at the top.

Select API key.

Copy your API key value and paste in the code below.

In Visual Studio, create a new .NET Framework Console App.
Go to Nuget Packet Manager.
Install Google.Apis.Youtube.v3 package.

```
    using System;
    using Google.Apis.Services;
    using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
    using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
    
    namespace GetYouTubeVideos
    {
       class Program
       {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
             GetVideos();
          }
          public static void GetVideos()
          {
             try
             {
                YouTubeService yt = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = "put api key here" });
                ChannelsResource.ListRequest channelsListRequest = yt.Channels.List("contentDetails");
                channelsListRequest.ForUsername = "put channel user name here";
// channelsListRequest.Id = "put channel id here (if you want to use the channel id)";
                ChannelListResponse channelsListResponse = channelsListRequest.Execute();
                foreach (Channel channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
                {
                   string uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;
                   string nextPageToken = "";
                   while (nextPageToken != null)
                   {
                      PlaylistItemsResource.ListRequest playlistItemsListRequest = yt.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                      playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                      playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                      playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
                      PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemsListResponse = playlistItemsListRequest.Execute();
                      foreach (PlaylistItem playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                      {
                         Console.WriteLine("Video Title= {0}, Video ID ={1}", playlistItem.Snippet.Title, playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                      }
                      nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
                   }
                }
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
             }
          }
       }
    }
```