# How to get caption from youtube data api

Tags: php, api, youtube, captions

I have struggled for some hours with this

From my understanding you need to first get the list of subtitles languages first – in their v3 data api it is called captions.list

From there, you have the list and ids of each caption attached to the video id.

Then, you can use captions.download theoretically with only the caption id. But for every video I tried it returns the same error.

> A service error occurred: The permissions associated with the request
>   are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might
>   not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled
>   third-party contributions for this caption.

I have even tried videos like – https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SY-mgZbuxBA – and seems that finding a video with enabled contributions is hard.

Is there any other way to get captions for a given youtube url ?

Comment: I have done in this way and it worked for me I have used Youtube API v3 from Nuget Packet manager following link @[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143202/get-all-videos-from-channel-youtube-api-v3-c-sharp/34148161#34148161](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143202/get-all-videos-from-channel-youtube-api-v3-c-sharp/34148161#34148161)

Comment: @digitalzoomstudio According to the doc you need following permission. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl` & `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner`. May be your access token is not authorised for above permissions. Did you try in google developer console?

Comment: It seems that download will only work with videos that have 3rd party contributions enabled